# How do I use one SSL cert across multiple domains with wordpress MU?

Tags: wordpress, ssl-certificate, multisite

So I have an SSL cert for mainsite.com

and I also have secondsite.com directing to mainsite.com/secondsite

but when I visit the page I keep getting this big ugly error.

screenshot:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/hljtcky2wdptzo7/Screenshot%202015-12-14%2022.02.14.png?dl=0

Is it possible to get all domains under one cert?

thanks.

Comment: That's definitely the wrong screenshot.

Comment: oops: proper screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/pya90fspsypzzdv/Screenshot%202015-12-16%2015.26.10.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Wrong screenshot...

But, you should check what certificate you bought. There are different types of certificates:

```
Certificate for 1 domain (only domainname.com)<
Certificate for 1 domains + 1 subdomain (domainname.com and sub.domainname.com)
Certificate for 1 domain unlimited subdomains (read above but unlimited subdomains)
Certificate for 5 domains (GeoTrust EV Multi Domain)
```

The last one is the most expensive one and I personally think you do not own this one.

EDIT: Some certificates allow you to use /subfolder/ to be included with your SSL.